# how can I use material-ui lab - checkboxestag component in another class component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an Add.js that contains the main Form. I have a CheckboxesTags.js that is a function component.
I need to get selected items of  CheckboxesTags.js in Add.js to send by axios with other values.
I added `<CheckboxesTags onChange={(e)=>{console.log(e.currentTarget);}}  />` but I cannot get values.

Add.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CheckboxesTags from './CheckboxesTags'

class Add extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

}

render() {
return (
<div >
        <CheckboxesTags onChange={(e)=>{console.log(this.props);}}  />
</div>
    )
}
}
export default Add;
```

and the CheckboxesTags.js is exactly material-ui code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import CheckBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBox';

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;



export default function CheckboxesTags() {

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      onChange={(e)=>{console.log(e.currentTarget);}}
      options={optins}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.name}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="Options" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
  );
}


let optins = [

];
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/products/notes').then(response => {
  optins = response.data
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to pass the click handler down from the parent component. Something like this (Not tested):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CheckboxesTags from './CheckboxesTags';

class Add extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleTagClick = tag => console.log(tag);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CheckboxesTags onSelect={this.handleTagClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Add;

import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import CheckBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CheckBox';

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

export default function CheckboxesTags(props) {
  const { onSelect } = props;
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      onChange={(event, value) => {
        onSelect(value);
      }}
      options={optins}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.name}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Options"
          placeholder="Favorites"
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Since you already have the `onChange` event attached to the `Autocomplete` element, this will fire any code contained within it. In this case it would be the passed down `onSelect` function.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to test format of `response.data` with `console.log(response.data)` cause `options` in `Autocomplete` is array.
If it is return objects of array you might need to use `Object.keys()`(to get the data object to an array) to get the `optins` array.